# Solr Suggester auto complete

Tags: php, solr

I'm new to solr search,i'm trying to implement auto suggestions in solr,finally i got something,here is the response:

```
<response>
     <lst name="responseHeader">
          <int name="status">0</int>
          <int name="QTime">4</int>
     </lst>
     <lst name="spellcheck">
     <lst name="suggestions">
     <lst name="h">
          <int name="numFound">3</int>
          <int name="startOffset">0</int>
          <int name="endOffset">1</int>
               <arr name="suggestion">
                     <str>hyderabad</str>
                     <str>hyd</str>
                     <str>holidays</str>
               </arr>
     </lst>
     <str name="collation">hyderabad</str>
     </lst>
     </lst>
  </response>
```

now i want to implement same thing in client side using php,ajax,solr response (wt=json),html.Can any one please suggest me how to implement this.